# Mongo field not being included in aggregation (PyMongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

### EDIT:

I was being silly, there was no data attribute in my scheme, only text. Got caught up looking at what the API was returning instead of how I was actually storing it in my db... oops. I'd remove the question if I knew how, hah.

---

### Initial question:

Here's my pipeline:

```py
    pipeline = [
        {"$match": {"matching_rules.tag": {"$eq": 'whale alert'}}},
        {"$project": {
            "data": {"text": 1},
            "matching_rules": {"$filter": {
                "input": '$matching_rules', 
                "as": 'item', 
                "cond": {"$eq": ['$$item.tag', 'whale alert']}
            }}
        }}
    ]
```

The data.text field isn't being included in the output, I've also tried `"data.text": 1`, and setting the int to a string (`"data.text": "1"`).

Here's some sample data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "13473....9220",
        "text": "...."
    },
    "matching_rules": [
        {
            "id": 1347....913984,
            "tag": "tweet verified"
        }
    ]
}
```

Current output:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5ff797bdde0ecfac5c94b79c'), 
'matching_rules': [{'id': 1347322179071913985, 'tag': 'whale alert'}]}, ...]
```

I'd like for the data.text to be in the output.

Comment: Sample source data and expected output would be useful

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added additional info now!